# Background service for sensor in android

Tags: java, android, service, android-sensors

I have implemented a code that opens an app when we shake our device. As far as i kept all my code into the MainActivity **and** without any background service, it all went well. But its not working when i tried to add a background service as **i want it keep working without going into an app every time.** So can anybody suggest me where am i doing wrong.Thanks!

**BackgroundService.java**

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    public BackgroundService() {
    }
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mSensor;
    private long lastUpdate = 0;
    private float last_x, last_y, last_z;
    private static final int SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 600;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Get sensor manager on starting the service.
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        // Registering...
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        // Get default sensor type
        mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // Get sensor manager on starting the service.
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        // Registering...
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        // Get default sensor type
        mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        return START_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not Yet Implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mySensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

            float[] values = sensorEvent.values;
            float x = values[0];
            float y = values[1];
            float z = values[2];

            long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
                long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
                lastUpdate = curTime;
                float speed
                        = Math.abs(x + y + z - last_x - last_y - last_z) / diffTime * 10000;
                if (speed > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
                    openWhatsApp();
                }
                last_x = x;
                last_y = y;
                last_z = z;
            }
            // Stop the sensor and service
               mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
               stopSelf();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
    }


    public void openWhatsApp() {
        Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
        if (launchIntent != null) {
            startService(launchIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundService.class);
        startService(i);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="joshipinak.com.shakeshooksaken">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <service android:name=".BackgroundService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Is this really a [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: Will keep that in mind from the next time. @loki :)

Comment: you could use rxJava instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [GitHub Android Examples](https://github.com/AndroidExamples/android-sensor-example) there is a complete app. It uses the command pattern like your code for checking the sensor values and `AlarmManager`.

In [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458797/how-to-register-a-background-service-as-a-sensoreventlistener-in-android) is an example using the `SensorEventListener` interface.

The Android developer site says to use `IntentService` on [this page](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service).
You can also read what is the difference between Service and IntentService in [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intentservice-in-the-android-platform).

These links may also help you:

- [A question on SO about having an Android app running in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404186/how-can-i-make-my-android-app-run-on-the-background)
- [Duplicate of previous link with other information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361837/how-can-i-make-my-android-application-run-in-background)
- [SO question about communication between Activity and Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging)